# Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, yolo

In sample code and OUTPUT below I am getting error "**Tensor is unhashable if Tensor equality is enabled. Instead, use tensor.experimental_ref() as the key.**"

Error occurs during `out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run()` part of the code in `detect_image()` method.

Is there a way to remove the placeholder component or solve the issue in any other way? I tried using `experimental_ref()` in the `detect_image()` method but it didn't work. Not sure if I had to do anything inside `generate()` method as well when placeholder is created.

I am also constrained with changing package versions (`keras`, `tensorflow`) to fix the issue.

```
from keras.models import load_model
import tensorflow.compat.v1.keras.backend as K
from yolo3.model import yolo_eval

   def generate(self):
        model_path = os.path.expanduser(self.model_path)
        assert model_path.endswith('.h5'), 'Keras model must be a .h5 file.'

        print("This is the model path:\n", model_path)

        self.yolo_model = load_model(model_path, compile=False)
        print('{} model, anchors, and classes loaded.'.format(model_path))

        # Generate colors for drawing bounding boxes.
        hsv_tuples = [(x / len(self.class_names), 1., 1.)
                      for x in range(len(self.class_names))]
        self.colors = list(map(lambda x: colorsys.hsv_to_rgb(*x), hsv_tuples))
        self.colors = list(
            map(lambda x: (int(x[0] * 255), int(x[1] * 255), int(x[2] * 255)),
                self.colors))
        random.seed(10101)  # Fixed seed for consistent colors across runs.
        random.shuffle(self.colors)  # Shuffle colors to decorrelate adjacent classes.
        random.seed(None)  # Reset seed to default.

        # Generate output tensor targets for filtered bounding boxes.
        self.input_image_shape = K.placeholder(shape=(2, ))
        boxes, scores, classes = yolo_eval(self.yolo_model.output, self.anchors,
                len(self.class_names), self.input_image_shape,
                score_threshold=self.score, iou_threshold=self.iou)

        xx_placeholders = [ op for op in self.sess.graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Placeholder"]
        print("Inside Generate:", xx_placeholders)

        print("Inside Generate:", boxes)
        print("Inside Generate:", scores)
        print("Inside Generate:", classes)

        return boxes, scores, classes

    def detect_image(self, image):
        if self.is_fixed_size:
            assert self.model_image_size[0]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            assert self.model_image_size[1]%32 == 0, 'Multiples of 32 required'
            boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, tuple(reversed(self.model_image_size)))
        else:
            new_image_size = (image.width - (image.width % 32),
                              image.height - (image.height % 32))
            boxed_image = letterbox_image(image, new_image_size)
        image_data = np.array(boxed_image, dtype='float32')

        print(image_data.shape)
        image_data /= 255.
        image_data = np.expand_dims(image_data, 0)  # Add batch dimension.

        print('A2')
        # XX: Checkpoint
        xx_placeholders = [ op for op in self.sess.graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Placeholder"]
        print("First:", xx_placeholders)

        print("boxes:", self.boxes)
        print("scores:", self.scores)
        print("classes:", self.classes)

        # self.yolo_model.input = image_data
        # self.input_image_shape = [image.size[1], image.size[0]]
        # K.set_learning_phase(0)
        # out_boxes = self.boxes(self.yolo_model.input, slef.input_image_shape, K.learning_phase())

        # print("New OutBoxes :", out_boxes)

        out_boxes, out_scores, out_classes = self.sess.run(
            [self.boxes, self.scores, self.classes],
            feed_dict={
                self.yolo_model.input: image_data,
                self.input_image_shape: [image.size[1], image.size[0]],
                K.learning_phase(): 0
            })
        ...

OUTPUT:

This is the model path:

C:/Program Files/Python35/Lib/site-packages/deep_sort_yolov3/model_data/yolo.h5

C:/Program Files/Python35/Lib/site-packages/deep_sort_yolov3/model_data/yolo.h5 model, anchors, and classes loaded.

Inside Generate: [< tf.Operation 'net/images' type=Placeholder >]

Inside Generate: Tensor("concat_11:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32)

Inside Generate: Tensor("concat_12:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)

Inside Generate: Tensor("concat_13:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32)

(416, 416, 3)

A2

First: [< tf.Operation 'net/images' type=Placeholder >]

boxes: Tensor("concat_11:0", shape=(None, 4), dtype=float32)

scores: Tensor("concat_12:0", shape=(None,), dtype=float32)

classes: Tensor("concat_13:0", shape=(None,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Here is a sample code that solves the issue but I am not able to replicate the same in above scenario.  

`import tensorflow as tf`
`x = tf.constant(5)`
`y = tf.constant(10)`
`z = tf.constant(20)`

# This will show same error.
`tensor_set = {x, y, z}`
`tensor_dict = {x: 'five', y: 'ten', z: 'twenty'}`

# This solves the issue
`tensor_set = {x.experimental_ref(), y.experimental_ref(), z.experimental_ref()}`
`tensor_dict = {x.experimental_ref(): 'five', y.experimental_ref(): 'ten', z.experimental_ref(): 'twenty'}`

Comment: To avoid the above error use latest version of Tensorflow and Keras. Thanks!